# Class diagram: how do I represent a relation which depends on another object?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have three classes: `A`, `B` and `C`. `A` has two arrays, one of `B` and one of `C`.

Each `C` has a index, which creates a relation to a `B` inside it's parent. If I substitute teh `B` array, every `C` now refer to a different `B`.

In a UML class diagram, how do I express: teh relation `C`->`B` which is a function of `A`?

EDIT: I have this:

[image: asd1]

And I want something like this:

[image: asd2]

(Perhaps this is reasonable? Thinking...)

Comment: I don't follow you with the substitution part, but else I offer you an answer.

Comment: Each `C` have only a index `i`, and refer to `A.array_of_b[i]`. Now you can `A.array_of_b = something_else`, and now every `C` refer `something_else[i]`.

Comment: I see. Unusual (FORTRAN-like) to use it rather than a object references. That invalidates my answer.

Comment: Maybe you enlighten us what you intend to do with accessing Bs from C, rather than presenting a solution in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your model would look like this:

[image]

You can navigate from `C` via the public `b` property of `A`.
You can be more specific about the array multiplicities from `A` if needed.

Rather than using an index, I would favor an object reference like the following:

[image]

The relation between `C` and `B` is an association. The little dot near `C` tells that `C` owns this association. But of course I don't know the intention of your design.

Comment: What is this kind of relation between B and C named?

Comment: see my added explanation in the answer